# Save attachments of selected messages in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, attachments, outlook-addin

I am looking for a way in Outlook 2010 to save attachments for selected messages. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not aware of any add-ins, but it should be possible to write a VBA macro/script in Outlook to do this. Would recommend some experience in programming though if you wanted to give it a go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of free utilities that offer some of the functionality you require:

[SaveAllAttachments](http://www.netpro.biz/saveallattachmentsol2007.html)
[OutlookAttachView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_attachment.html)
[Outlook Attachment Remover](http://www.kopf.com.br/outlook/)

I can offer no advice on how reliable/usable these are as I personaly use [EZdetach](http://www.techhit.com/ezdetach/outlook_attachments.html) from TechHit which is superb - albeit not free.  However, EZDetach and their Simplyfile tool together save me hours every week.  Well worth the small price tag.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for some add-in or utility that could help me save attachments of selected emails in Outlook 2010 but for free. I found [OutlookAttachView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_attachment.html) after some googling. It's not Outlook add-in and a standalone utility but worked great for me. I tried its 64-bit version when I tested it.